# Showing messages on the GUI

Tags: oracle, plsql, message

Sorry if the question sounds weird. I am using an ERP system having the Front End made in COBOL and the back end in Oracle PL/SQL. What I want is to include a condition in the background PL/SQL procedure and based on the result, I want to show a Pop-up or Notification like message to the user's screen. So far, I am unable to find a way to print a message on Windows through PL/SQL. Is it doable?

Comment: I've removed the `cobol` tag, added in a previous edit. If you want to ask something directly related to your front-end, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PL/SQL` works only at the database level. It has no access to whatever front end is using it.

Basically, there would be 2 approaches to show a message produced by PL/SQL on the front end:

- First one would be to use `raise_application_error` with a custom error code and the message you want to show. This would raise an "exception" that you would need to handle in the front end to show the message . You can use any code in the range `-20000..-20999` for the error code. In my humble opinion, this is a *crude and not recommendable* approach, but still it would work.
- The second approach would consist in making you PL/SQL return some message, either as a `result` of a function or as an `out parameter`. Once you have the message just show it in your front end.

Comment: Thanks. raise_application_error fits my needs as I wanted to print a logical error based on some conditions.